# How do I debug a mount failure with permission denied even tho I running with sudo?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, sudo

How do I debug a mount failure with `permission denied` given I ran it with sudo?

Why would a sudo command ever result in permission denied?

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir foo bar
$ sudo mount --bind ./foo/ ./bar/
mount: /workspaces/codespace-container/bar: permission denied.

$ ll
drwxrwxrwx+ 8 vscode root   4096 Jul 17 06:10 ./
drwxr-xrwx+ 5 vscode root   4096 Jul 16 07:31 ../
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 vscode vscode 4096 Jul 17 06:10 bar/
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 vscode vscode 4096 Jul 17 06:10 foo/

$ getfacl bar
# file: bar
# owner: vscode
# group: vscode
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

The docker file uses `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:0-jammy` as the base image
and does nothing to specifically alter permissions. The full docker file can be found `https://github.com/kingces95/codespace-container/blob/main/.devcontainer/Dockerfile` and its variables `https://github.com/kingces95/codespace-container/blob/main/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`.

My overarching goal is to mount directories in this codespace `https://github.com/kingces95/codespace-container` that is built with devcontainer just like I can in the default codespace.

---

Googling "How to debug permission denied" >
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375872/how-do-i-debug-filesystem-permissions > https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/ > Suggests trying to use strace

```
$ strace sudo mount --bind ./foo/ ./bar/
```

which yields this little gem at the end:

> effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the
> '**nosuid**' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Comment: Try to add some content into `./foo`.

Comment: Still get the error. I'm able to run this same command in the default codespace. It's just when I use this different base image I get the error. Just not sure what it means when a sudo command generated a permissions error!

Comment: May be related to nosuid -- https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/6471

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682297/getting-message-sudo-must-be-setuid-root-but-sudo-is-already-owned-by-root/19306929#19306929 and https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1100 -- sudo needs to be owned by root and hosted in a file system that supports the SUID bit. So maybe sudo metadata is bad? Except I can login as root and I still get the error -- but maybe that's for a different reason...

Comment: More good stuff on playing with suid flags - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250802/effect-of-nosuid-on-executables-inside-the-mounted-filesystem

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/488. Looks like the base image I'm using needs to be started as root. In my docker file I have a line `USER vscode`. Maybe I just need to undo that line...

Answer (score 1):

In `devcontainer.json` add

```
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined",
        "--privileged",
        "--init"
    ],
```

That's what the default `universal` container uses. See `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/main/containers/codespaces-linux/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`. It's probably that `--privileged` flag. Will open a PR against the `devcontainer.json` template to add that block